# Difference between a tap and a hosepipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

When the flow of water through a tap is blocked by the fingers, the water does not increase in velocity whereas the velocity of water increases when the same is done tp a hosepipe. Both involve the equation of continuity but why is the behaviour different?

Comment: I've just tried putting my finger over a tap (with the water on) and it increased the water velocity exactly as it does with a hosepipe. Maybe your tap and your hosepipe have different water pressures.

Comment: It could be that your pipes or whatever are made from some non-flexible material so that it doesn't allow the pressure to build up.